# Soundcloud Api / Reposts Endpoint

Tags: javascript, api, soundcloud

I've always used this for my repost requests

```
SC.put("/e1/me/track_reposts/track_id");
```

but it seems like they disabled it or that it just doesn't work atm.

Is there any solution to this? Any second way? They have 0 documentation about this on their site which is weird. I'm using Javascript for this

Comment: For those wondering, this works!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will have to update to the latest Soundcloud SDK